# Initials from two names plus full surname

Tags: java, names

I'm struggling with this code. Return of this one is eg: "JS John Smith" but when I try to put two names plus surname all I get is a mess. I wish to get when I type eg: "John William Smith" something like this: "JW Smith", anybody know hot to do it?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class ex54 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        String fullName = null;
        try{
            fullName = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        int spacePos = fullName.indexOf(" ");
        // String firstName = fullName.substring(0, spacePos);
        // String secondName = fullName.substring(1, spacePos);
        String firstInitial = fullName.substring(0, 1);
        String secondInitial = fullName.substring(spacePos+1, spacePos+2);
        String userName = (firstInitial + secondInitial + " ").concat(fullName);

        System.out.println("Hello, your user name is: " + userName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good candidate for `split`

Answer (score 1):

You can split the name, assuming you are given a three-name string:

```
String[] names = fullname.split(" ");
System.out.println("" + names[0].charAt(0) + names[1].charAt(0) + " " + names[2]);
```

Comment: Not general purpose. Fails if no middle name is given, and produces incorrect result if multiple middle names are given.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int spacePos = -1;

    System.out.print("Hello, your user name is:");
    do {
        System.out.print(" "+fullName.substring(spacePos+1, spacePos+2));
        fullName = fullName.substring(spacePos+1);
        spacePos = fullName.indexOf(" ");
    }while(spacePos != -1);
    System.out.println("\b"+fullName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks, here is an implementation using regular expressions:

```
private static String firstNamesToInitials(String name) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b([A-Z])[A-Za-z]*\\b").matcher(name);
    String lastName = null;
    while (m.find()) {
        buf.append(m.group(1));
        lastName = m.group();
    }
    if (buf.length() <= 1)
        return lastName;
    buf.setCharAt(buf.length() - 1, ' ');
    return buf.append(lastName).toString();
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(firstNamesToInitials("Cher"));
System.out.println(firstNamesToInitials("John Smith"));
System.out.println(firstNamesToInitials("John William Smith"));
System.out.println(firstNamesToInitials("Charles Philip Arthur George"));
System.out.println(firstNamesToInitials("Pablo Diego José Francisco de Paula Juan Nepomuceno María de los Remedios Cipriano de la Santísima Trinidad Ruiz y Picasso"));
```

*Output*

```
Cher
J Smith
JW Smith
CPA George
PDFPJNRCTR Picasso
```